# MySQL ошибка 3065

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Имею ошибку MySQL 3065.

> Query Error Query: 
>       SELECT DISTINCT p.*,p.id,p.ext,p.hash,p.status 
>           FROM photos_photo p 
>           JOIN photos_album_photos ap ON p.id = ap.photo_id 
>           WHERE ap.album_id = 1 AND p.status = 1 
>                                 AND p.url IS NOT NULL 
>                                 AND LENGTH(TRIM(p.url)) > 0 
>                                 AND p.parent_id = 0 
>           ORDER BY ap.sort ASC LIMIT 500
>
> Error: 3065 Message: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'ss.ap.sort' which is not in SELECT
>   list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Разработчик ПО молчит, подскажите куда копать?
Был перенос с одного `VPS` на другой скрипта интернет магазина.
база импортирована как с помощью `sypex dumper` 
так и стандартными *mysqldump* - эффект не меняется, ранние базы такой же эффект.

Стоит *mysqld 5.7.12-0ubuntu1*. Раньше была старее версия. мне кажется проблема в MySQL.

Comment: копайте в сторону отключения режима ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY или правки запроса под вашу, более новую версию mysql

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, вам нужно включить в селект ap.sort

Answer (score 1):

Решение и правда было в ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Расскажу как победил

```
mysql -u root -p

mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,", ""));

mysql> SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,", ""));
```

тем самым меняем значение на прежнее, но за исключением подстроки "only_full_group_by,".
Проверить результат и убедиться что режим выключен можно командой:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Comment: на самом деле это не правильный путь, так как сортировка в таком запросе может вести себя не предсказуемо. Но если подобных запросов в проекте уже много, то действительно проще отключить этот режим и принимать решение, переписывать все запросы или забить если не критично.

Comment: помогло `mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,", "")); mysql> SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,", ""));`